# Fabric v1.4.2 Chaincode Error - You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to invoke a method of a chaincode that I have implemented using the Fabric NodeJS SDK.

The chaincode is implemented using `"fabric-shim" v1.4.2` while the Nodejs SDK used is `"fabric-network" v1.4.1`.

When I invoke the method I get this error:

> Error: transaction returned with failure:
>
> Error: You've asked to
>   invoke a function that does not exist: com.example.mycompany.myContract.myMethod

If I try to retrieve the metadata invoking the `"org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata"` I see that method is successfully registered.

Here my chaincode:

```
const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class myContract extends Contract {

    constructor(){
        super("com.example.mycompany.myContract");
    }

    async myMethod(ctx, data){

        //Logics go here

        return myResult;
    }

}

module.exports = myContract;
```

Any idea about why I'm not able to invoke the method?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, I was invoking the method in the wrong way (I forgot the `:`).

Below the right way to invoke it:

```
com.example.mycompany.myContract:myMethod
```

Comment: correct - `namespace:transaction` (where a contract namespace is used)

Comment: can you explain the exact solution?